# Как получить имя доменой учетной записи в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возможно ли в запросе получить имя учетки не той от чего имени выполняется запрос, а той под кем залогинены на ПК? С БД работает ПО от единого прописанного пользователя, на столбец повесил триггер и хочу понимать какой юзер выполняет действия, к исходному коду ПО доступа нет.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, то если аутентификация на сервер виндовая, то без проблем через `suser_sname()`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174427.aspx). Вот статья по именам пользователей MS SQL: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191126(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @BlackWitcher дополнил вопрос.

Comment: запрос выполняется всегда от имени пользователя базы данных, независимо от пользователя ОС

Comment: @Anatol это понятно, я подумал может есть инструмент который определяет пользователя ОС.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос - нет. Штатными средствами - никак.

Логика такая - сервер, это отдельная изолированная сущность, которая знать не знает ничего о том, кто и под каким именем работает на компьютере.

Грубо говоря, для выполнения запросов нужно подключиться к серверу. После подключения вся работа с сервером выполняется от имени того пользователя, который был подключен к серверу.

Сам сервер знает имя и пароль этого пользователя, и не более. Для того, что бы сервер смог вам выдать имя пользователя, который у вас залогинен в операционной системе, MS SQL должен уметь опрашивать на этот счет операционную систему. Но зачем это ему? Так что сервер не умеет опрашивать винду и узнавать какой пользователь там залогинен, ибо как это вообще относится к функциям сервера и базам данных? Никак.

Но есть один момент, когда для подключению к серверу используется механизм аутентификации Windows. В этом случае система аутентификации Windows и MS-SQL взаимодействуют. В этом случае для авторизации на сервере используются учетные данные Windows. **И только в этом случае имя пользователя в Windows и на MS SQL Server совпадают.**

Но вот уже дальнейшие распределения прав на объекты внутри сервера обеспечиваются самим сервером, вне зависимости от роли учетной записи Windows.

Итого, получаем, что варианты у нас крайне ограничены:

1. Подключаться к БД через windows-аутентификацию, тогда имя домена и учетной записи будет передано внутрь сервера. Но это не всегда возможно.
2. Передавать серверу имя домена и пользователя из клиента самостоятельно (нужно подумать, каким именно способом).

   2а. Можно попробовать заставлять сервер самостоятельно, каждый раз при подключении пользователя выполнять какой-то внешний инструмент (программу), которая получала бы имя пользователя Windows, подключалась к серверу, и записывала бы в отдельную таблицу имя виндового пользователя, который подключился к серверу.

Но п. 2 и 2а сами по себе мне кажутся очень неудобными, громоздкимии кривыми костылями.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попытаться определить машину пользователя, с которой пришло подключение

```
   SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName
```

и таким образом идентифицировать того, кто работает с БД на этой машине.

Однако это не всегда будет работать, поскольку хост может определиться, как имя программы, типа "Microsoft Office" и т.п.

Comment: ПО стоит на удаленном сервере и пользователи с ПО работают через RDP - то есть машина всегда одна...

Comment: @Winteriscoming тогда без вариантов.

Comment: @Winteriscoming можете попробовать добавлять в запрос уникальный идентификатор

Comment: И что вам скажет имя хоста в случае, если мы имеем дело скажем, с доменом Active Directory и на хост можно зайти любой доменной учёткой?

Comment: @AK это к кому вопрос?